# PayPal Gateway Integration in ASP.Net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, paypal

I want to integrate PayPal Gateway in my website. I want a return URL with required parameter like other payment gateway have, which returns some parameter saying payment successful and transaction ID etc.

Comment: use Payment data transfer or Instant Payment Notification

Answer (score 3):

In web.config

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="token" value="PW1BDVNqVPVanwduF_Tb2Ey91aT1Uhx1kL7HPc-7e8S-6AnUwSSHyasolSe"/>
    <add key="paypalemail" value="@gmail.com"/>
    <add key="PayPalSubmitUrl" value="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr"/>
    <add key="FailedURL" value="http://www.mrsoft.co.in/ProceedToPayment.aspx"/>
    <add key="SuccessURL" value="http://www.mrsoft.co.in/ProceedToPayment.aspx"/>
</appSettings>
```

Code

```
protected void PayWithPayPal(string amount, string itemInfo, string name, string phone, string email, string currency)
{ 
    string redirecturl = "";

    //Mention URL to redirect content to paypal site
    redirecturl += "https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_xclick&business=" + 
               ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["paypalemail"].ToString();

    //First name i assign static based on login details assign this value
    redirecturl += "&first_name=" + name;

    //City i assign static based on login user detail you change this value
    redirecturl += "&city=bhubaneswar";

    //State i assign static based on login user detail you change this value
    redirecturl += "&state=Odisha";

    //Product Name
    redirecturl += "&item_name=" + itemInfo;

    //Product Name
    redirecturl += "&amount=" + amount;

    //Phone No
    redirecturl += "&night_phone_a=" + phone;

    //Product Name
    redirecturl += "&item_name=" + itemInfo;

    //Address 
    redirecturl += "&address1=" + email;

    //Business contact id
    // redirecturl += "&business=k.tapankumar@gmail.com";

    //Shipping charges if any
    redirecturl += "&shipping=0";

    //Handling charges if any
    redirecturl += "&handling=0";

    //Tax amount if any
    redirecturl += "&tax=0";

    //Add quatity i added one only statically 
    redirecturl += "&quantity=1";

    //Currency code 
    redirecturl += "&currency=" + currency;

    //Success return page url
    redirecturl += "&return=" + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SuccessURL"].ToString();

    //Failed return page url
    redirecturl += "&cancel_return=" + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FailedURL"].ToString();

    Response.Redirect(redirecturl);
}
```

Comment: Hi Mehul, Can you please tell me how to get the token number ?

Comment: Ya i think below artical  give full information to you                                                                      http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42894/Introduction-to-PayPal-for-C-ASP-NET-developers

Comment: @MehulBhalala Do no share token number publicly

Answer (score 0):

for [return Url](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42894/Introduction-to-PayPal-for-C-ASP-NET-developers#PostPayment) see..

for Html variable [see](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/)

for mvc integration of paypal [see](http://logcorner.wordpress.com/2013/09/05/asp-net-mvc-paypal-integration/)

you can download [NopCommerce2.8](http://www.nopcommerce.com/downloads.aspx) or http://nopcommerce.codeplex.com/   with source code. It has implemented Paypal (all methods) and manyothers payment gateway.

http://www.superstarcoders.com/blogs/posts/paypal-with-asp-net-mvc.aspx

http://www.mindstick.com/Articles/41de052a-37e1-41db-aa4c-123313be444a/?How%20to%20integrate%20PayPal%20in%20A

http://blog.liamcavanagh.com/2012/06/how-to-use-paypal-with-asp-net-mvc/

see about "custom" html variable...

i got dirty way ...in "return" html variable to pass id ... /Event/RedirectFromPaypal?eventId=26 ..

### "Help as openSource... :)"